# Can't boot Live USB Live from grub (failed to find fs)

Tags: 16.04, grub2, kernel, live-usb

**Context** :

I have tried to reinstall Linux Ubuntu on my laptop - along with windows - but after reboot GRUB starts in command line.

I've tried some manipulations and end to supress the partitions dedicated to ubuntu (from windows disk manager) - I realize it was probably not a good idea..

Thus, reinstalling Ubuntu from a USB Key now seems the unique option.

**Problem** :

Trying to boot from a Live USB (freshly created with the last Ubuntu LTS 16.04.03 image), I've entered the following commands :

```
set root=(hd0)
chainloader /EFI/BOOT/BOOTx64.EFI
boot
```

but it returns the following message :

```
Booting in insecure mode
Failed to find fs: Unsupported
Failed to load image \EFI\BOOT\grubx64.efi: Unsupported
start_image() returned Unsupported
error: unknown error.
```

Do you have an idea of what's possible to do ?

Comment: You normally boot an installer directly  from UEFI/BIOS, not from another grub.  & how you boot UEFI or BIOS is then how it installs. If you have booted into grub with UEFI, then you are not using UEFI's default of /EFI/Boot/bootx64,.efi (for external devices or fallback entry) but need to boot grubx64.efi. In trying to do this with a CD/DVD, I found case to also be important, but with flash drive and FAT32, case should not matter.

Comment: Hi Olfred, thanks for your answer !

I have found a way to boot on the live USB by copying instructions related to "Try Ubuntu without installing"  as written in `EFI/boot/grub/grub.cfg`, completing them with `set root` and `boot`:
<pre>
    set root=(hd0) 
    set gfxpayload=keep
 linux /casper/vmlinuz.efi  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper quiet splash ---
    initrd /casper/initrd.lz
    boot
<code>

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have found a way to boot on the live USB by copying instructions related to "Try Ubuntu without installing"  as written in`/boot/grub/grub.cfg`, completing them with `set root` and `boot` :

```
set root=(hd0) 
set gfxpayload=keep
linux   /casper/vmlinuz.efi  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper quiet splash ---
initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
boot
```